# how to get the root folder project from child folder?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the root project folder from child of childs folders , and then save the output to debug using python code instead of adding the path static

my tree path looks like this

```
.
├── ChangeLog
├── core
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── models
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── utils.py
│   │   └── templates
├── debug
│   └── debug.log
```

```
fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
parentDir = os.path.dirname(fileDir)
print(parentDir) # /home/xxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/core
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import core and use it's `__file__` attribute to get it's path.

```py
import os
import core

coreDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(core.__file__))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path

root = Path(__file__).parent
```